# Remove the 0 decimals from a string using regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like: `String value = "0.0232300";`  and I want to remove those two 0 from the decimal part (the 0 which are after number 3) without parsing the `String` to `Double`. Is the any way to do this using String methos or regex?

Comment: `value.replaceAll("0+$", "")`.

Comment: Looks like you are looking to create a regex, but do not know where to get started. Please check [Reference - What does this regex mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618) resource, it has plenty of hints. Also, refer to [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736) post for some basic regex info. Once you get some expression ready and still have issues with the solution, please edit the question with the latest details and we'll be glad to help you fix the problem.

Comment: @AndyTurner Try it with `20000`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sure. Depends on exactly what OP means by "I have a string like..." as to whether you need to care about that.

Comment: @AndyTurner all is clear: *remove those two 0 **from the decimal part***

Comment: @AndyTurner thank you very much for your answer. It works for 0.2200 but it does not work for 2200.